# Has anything been made which takes place after Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars

After Star Wars VI was made, AFAIK everything since then that has been made for TV/cinema has been set before Star Wars IV.

Prequels as far as the eye can see...

Has anything been made which takes place after Star Wars VI?

Comment: no official cannon has been made, though currently it is being made, there is plenty of stuff out their past part 6, but its all lower/not official cannon.

Comment: Movies or books? There's an enormous extended universe of books.

Comment: I gather they'll be making a film that follows Return of the Jedi. You heard it here first...

Comment: -1 for not bothering with even the most basic research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short answer: No.

According to Leland Chee, the keeper of the Star Wars continuity:

> The only relevant official continuities are the current versions of the films alone.

## Longer answer: no, yes, and yes.

Since a reorganization made on April 25, 2014, there have been three levels of Star Wars canon. These levels are:

- **Canon** - Episodes 1-6. *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, *Star Wars Rebels*, information on the StarWars.com Databank, and all officially-licensed source material released starting with "A New Dawn" (released September 2, 2014.) Episodes 7+ will presumably fall under this category as well, but as of today, nothing on the list above occurred after the destruction of the second Death Star.
- **Legends** - All of the previous Extended Universe material. Books, comics, games, and RPG sourcebooks. At this point, Legends is essentially unofficial and non-canon, but is considered a valid "inspiration resource". If you follow DC, the relationship of pre-Crisis to post-Crisis timelines is a good analogy. The EU fills several decades after episode 6, including both Luke and Leia's children, a new Jedi order, new Sith, and other threats to the galaxy.
- **Non-canon**: Essentially everything else. "What-if" stories, crossover appearances, game statistics, etc. There's all kinds of garbage in this category.

(Text mostly adapted from Wikipedia.)

Comment: The *Clone Wars* TV series, and now *Rebels* are both fully canon.

Comment: This is the old version of the Star Wars canon. Now that Disney has taken over, there are three categories: Canon, Legends, and Non-canon. Legends is all the EU that was published before Disney took over.

Comment: @jliv902 Updated my answer to reflect this new organization.

Answer (score 5):

In the Expanded Universe yes, there have been stories told that fill out 40-50 years after RotJ. This has all been declared to no longer be official canon and there are new movies being created that will essentially tell the next tales in the story. This is because virtually every square inch of story has been told about the primary characters, including some of them dying. So really it left no wiggle room to tell story in the new films without stepping on toes left, right and center. Disney/Lucasfilm decided to clean the slate and make all the books/comics/video games etc to no longer be official cannon.

Comment: If only my own lifes canon was so easy to delete and rewrite

Answer (score 4):

Plutor's answer is the most technically correct, but there are several further divisions in the Expanded Universe.

Like he noted, all the 'old stuff' (e.g. that published prior to April 25, 2014) is considered "Legends". The current canon works begin with the novel *A New Dawn*, and anything published after it is in the new continuity, such as the upcoming novels *Tarkin* and *Lords of the Sith*.

As for the old EU works post-*Return of the Jedi*, they fell into several major divisions.

## New Republic Era

*5.5 ABY (years After Battle of Yavin) to 22 ABY*

Starting with *Luke Skywalker and the Shadows of Mindor* and ending with *Survivor's Quest*, this era contains many of the *X-Wing* series, several stand-alone trilogies such as *The Jedi Academy Trilogy* and *The Black Fleet Crisis*, numerous self-contained novels such as *The Crystal Star* and *Planet of Twilight*, but most notably, the novels that are somewhat widely considered the best in the entire EU, Timothy Zahn's *Thrawn Trilogy* (IMO, the biggest "Must-Read" for the hardcore Star Wars fan).

In this era, the fledgling New Republic continues beating back the Empire, putting down several resurgences, and many of the EU's most loved characters are introduced here.

## New Jedi Order Era

*24.5 ABY to 36 ABY*

Starting with the e-book novella *Boba Fett: A Practical Man*, and ending with *The Dark Nest Trilogy*, this era contains mostly the lenghty *New Jedi Order* series, which covers 5 years by itself, and met with fairly mixed reviews - a lot of love/hate for it.

In this era, the New Republic faces a massive extragalactic invasion and the Jedi Order as a whole is shaken to its foundations. Several beloved characters face major changes or even death during this era.

## Legacy Era

*40 ABY to 45 ABY*

Starting with the *Legacy of the Force* series and ending with *Crucible*, the latest chronologically published novel, this era primarily contains *Legacy* and the *Fate of the Jedi* series(es).

In this era, a new arising of the Sith from an unexpected place and an ancient terror change the course of the galaxy. At this point, the main characters are primarily EU constructions, with Luke, Leia, and Han being major role players, but not the central focus. The final book does not really close out the storyline, but is not a direct cliffhanger.

## Legacy/Cade Skywalker Era

*130 ABY to 138 ABY*

Though this does not appear in any novels, there is a significant comic series (*Star Wars Legacy*) primarily dealing with Cade Skywalker, a direct descendant of Luke Skywalker, though unknown exactly to what generation. Much of the series deals with a reborn Sith empire known as the One Sith, very different from the Sith structure under Darth Bane. Lead by Darth Krayt, this empire causes conflict across the galaxy that Cade is caught up in. By this time, all the characters from the other post-Rotj EU are dead, although no backstory is given, so only the loosest connection to the beginning of the Legacy era is given.

Comment: You're missing the Cade Skywalker era

Comment: @DVK - I forgot about that - I've only read the novels.

Comment: @DVK - ahh, I see. I read all the EU novels after NJO, but no comics at any point. I have read Wookiepedia a lot, but it's been awhile

Answer (score 2):

As of 2015, Disney's new canon contains events post-ROTJ, notably, events of ***Episode VII* ("The Force Awakens")** dealing with the conflict between Resistance and First Order (and the fate of Luke, Leia and Han 20 years later).

There are several new canon works (mostly books) spanning the 20 years between Episode VI and VII, such as *Aftermath* novels and direct TFA prequel works.